# AJAX Post to Rails controller with foreign key

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 2 models:

```
class Document
    has_many :citations
end

class Citations
    belongs_to :document
end
```

How can I get the `document_id` on the client side to add to the object literal I am sending to the controller?

Example of the hash I am sending to the `create` method of the `CitationsController`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        citation: {
            document_id: //need this
            quote: 'quote'
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML data-* attributes to hold such values as they are part of HTML standard. For example if you trigger your AJAX Post request with a click on a link, this link could be defines like this:

```
= link_to "trigger", "#", "data-document_id" => document.id
```

Then in JavaScript you extract the attribute value from the triggering element.

The snippet above is a very specific example and perhaps doesn't apply to your use case, but hope you get the idea.